Double integrals: strange accuracy behavior
In double integrals: when x-y region is rectangular as in
$$\int_0^3\int_0^3(x^2+y^2) \, dy \, dx $$
accuracy of Simpson 1/3 rule is better than that of Trapezoidal rule which in turn is better than that of 0-degree interpolation, which is normal and expected. But when the x-y region is curved as in
$$\int_0^3\int_{0.1 \, x^2}^{5 - 0.05 \, x^2}(x^2+y^2) \, dy \, dx $$
I find that 0-degree interpolation accuracy is better than that of the Trapezoidal rule (1st degree interpolation) which is also better than that of Simpson 1/3 rule. This is very weird.
I can’t find an explanation for that.
Can anyone explain why is this the case?
Update: corrected y upper bound in second double integral

Can you explain how you are performing trapezoid, Simpsons, etc. on a nonrectangular domain? They are methods designed for intervals

Trapezoidal (backward sum) : I = $$ \frac{\Delta x}{4}  , \sum_{i = 1}^m  , \Delta y , \sum_{j = 1}^n  [f(x_{i-1},y_{j-1} )+  f(x_{i-1},y_{j} )+  f(x_{i},y_{j-1} )+  f(x_{i},y_{j} )]$$

How are you defining $y_i$ and $\Delta y$ when the bounds on $y$ depend on $x$?

Your second integral is not a valid double integral because the upper and lower bounds switch over course of the $x$ ranging from $0$ to $3$

Simpson 1/3: I = $$ \frac{\Delta x}{9}  , \sum_{i = 2}^m  , \Delta y , \sum_{j = 2}^n  [A + B + C], \quad A = f(x_{i-2},y_{j-2} )+  4 , f(x_{i-2},y_{j-1} )+  f(x_{i-2},y_{j} ),  \quad B =  4 , f(x_{i-1},y_{j-2} )+  16 , f(x_{i-1},y_{j-1} )+  4 , f(x_{i-1},y_{j} ), \quad C = f(x_{i},y_{j-2} )+  4 , f(x_{i},y_{j-1} )+  f(x_{i},y_{j} )  \quad\quad i = 2, 4, , \cdots , m, \quad j = 2, 4, \cdots, n $$ , m and n are even

$$\Delta y  = (y_2(x_i) - y_1(x_i)), \quad\quad y_j = y_1(x_i) + j , \Delta y , \quad\quad  y_{j -1}= y_1(x_i) + (j -1) , \Delta y , $$ … etc $$y_1(x) = 0.1 , x^2 , \quad\quad y_2(x) = 5 - 0.5 , x^2 $$ , … etc

Why i can’t edit my own comments?
$$ \Delta y = (y_2(x_i) - y_1(x_i)/n$$

Comments can only be edited within the first five minutes of being posted. That's one reason we encourage posters to edit their question rather than adding repeated comments.

I think I found the problem:
I changed $\Delta y$ from:
$$ \Delta y = (y_2(x_i) - y_1(x_i))/n $$
to
$$ \Delta y = (y_2(x_{i-1}) - y_1(x_{i-1}))/n $$
This improved accuracy and it’s way better.
$\Delta y$ changes with $x_i$ and is not constant in curved regions unlike rectangular ones.
In each iteration 3 points are used $x_i$, $x_{i-1}$ and $x_{i-2}$
I think using the middle point $x_{i-1}$ in calculating $\Delta y$ improved the accuracy and solved the problem.
